# Can a decimal multiplied by another decimal ever equal an integer?

Tags: arithmetic

Any decimal number between 0 and infinity that multiplied by itself or another decimal number. Like 0.4 times 0.25, 2.425 times 2.425 and so on.

Comment: What you mean by "decimal"? A noninteger? A noninteger with finite decimal expansion?

Comment: What do you mean by decimal? A number with fractional part?

Comment: Do you mean like $2/5=0.4$ and $5/2=2.5$.

Comment: hmm .... quite a brainteaser!

Comment: Side note: if by "decimal" you somehow mean a number strictly between $0$ and $1$, then no.  If $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ you will have $0<xy<1$, further implying that $xy$ is not an integer.  I doubt that is what is intended, but without you explaining yourself it is still a possible interpretation.

Comment: The curve $xy=n$ has infinitely many points with both coordinates decimal for all non-zero integer $n$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, $\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2} = 2$.

Answer (score 5):

Since nobody has given example where both terminate:

$$2.5\times 0.4=1$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes. $0.\overline 6\cdot 1.5=\frac23\cdot \frac32=1$.

Answer (score 2):

A tad tongue in cheek:

$$2.0 \times 3.0 = 6$$

Answer (score 1):

Take a $2$ rationals: $\dfrac{4}{3} = 1.3333...$, and its reciprocal $\dfrac{3}{4} = 0.75$, what is their product ?